# Is it possible to use multiple headers in php?

Tags: php

I have a website that has a few pages (Homepage, FAQ, and How-it-works) that use everything in the header. But the rest of the site only needs the stylesheets and js.

There are some elemements in the header that kind of slow down the page speed, so to avoid that with the rest of the site, is it possible to do something like this:

header.php 
header1.php
header2.php

for the different pages on the site?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Boy, the first sentence really threw me off when I thought you meant HTTP headers. You can include whatever and however and wherever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible approaches spring to mind. One is to dynamically load different header files based on the file name:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == "page1.php")
{
    include_once "header1.php";
}
else
{
    include_once "header2.php";
}
```

The other is to just hide the unwanted content in the one header using an IF statement:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == "page1.php")
{
?>
<!-- Optional content here -->
<?php
}
```

I think the latter approach is probably the more elegant solution.

Comment: Would the standard include work?: 

<?php include('header1.php'); ?>

Comment: Yes, the regular include is fine too.